# Outlook AddIn using Visual Studio 2019 and Office Fabric UI React

Tags: reactjs, outlook-web-addins, office-fabric

I am trying to develope a new Outlook AddIn using the highly recommended Office UI Fabric React. However, I am very comfortable with Visual Studio and would like to take advantage of the multiple helpful features of the software. Is there a way I can harness the power of both components together? I don't want to have to use Visual Studio Code and the command line. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can use Visual Studio for web addin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-and-debug-office-add-ins-in-visual-studio)  Is this question more about using Office Fabric UI React in visual studio?   Are there particular features you plan to use in Visual Studio?  You can still use Visual Studio for changes and debugging after a solution is initially set up.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am under the impression that to create and develop an add in that supports react I can not create it with Visual Studio. Hence if I want to use Fabric React I cannot use Visual Studio. Is this correct?

Comment: And what do you mean by "You can still use Visual Studio for changes and debugging after a solution is initially set up"? Can you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Let's go back to how you are planning to use use Visual Studio for, and how you are planning to create your initial addin.  Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=yeomangenerator?  You can use Visual Studio for editing.  For debugging, sorry, I was not clear, it would work in some platforms https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-and-debug-office-add-ins-in-visual-studio

Comment: I've read these links and have created my outlook add-in in this way. However I am looking to use Fabric UI React and I didn't see how I can make an add-in with react on Visual Studio. Can you tell me how to do that? I was only able to create it with the yoeman generator but then I couldn't run it from Visual Studio. I want to run it from visual studio so I can debug on my desktop outlook.

Comment: In general we use VSCode when working with node.js/Fabric UI React. Doing so with Visual Studio is a route we haven't explored. However I'm sure there's a way to use Visual Studio with node.js/Fabric UI React. This might be good starting point https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2019. Afterwards you should be able to integrate our add-in API.